# Ngx-Datatable - How to handle a boolean data of a row

Tags: angular, typescript, boolean, angular-ng-if, ngx-datatable

I'm definitely missing something but I can't manage the boolean value of a row ...

what I want is to make a certain string appear if it is true and another string if it is false.

This is what I had done but it doesn't work, it always takes the value (boolean) of the row:

```
<ngx-datatable
class="material striped"
[headerHeight]="'auto'"
[footerHeight]="'auto'"
[columnMode]="'force'"
[rows]="aziones"
[rowHeight]="'auto'"
modelService="modelService"
[sortType]="'single'"
[reorderable]="true"
[limit]="10"
[sorts]="[{prop: 'id', dir: 'asc'}]"
[messages]="{totalMessage: 'totali', emptyMessage: 'Nessun dato'}"
>
 <ngx-datatable-column name="Stato" [sortable]="true" [canAutoResize]="true" prop='status'>
  <ng-template *ngIf="!aziones" let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template *ngIf="!aziones && row['status'] === false" let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
    <span>Passivo!!!</span>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template *ngIf="!aziones && row['status'] === true" let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
    <span>Attivo!!!</span>
  </ng-template>
 </ngx-datatable-column>
```

surely it is banal, can someone explain to me how to do it?
thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

I'm working in a similar thing. I'm doing this

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="Aprobado" prop="aprobado" >
    <ng-template let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          <span *ngIf="value === false">No Aprobado</span>
          <span *ngIf="value === true">Aprobado</span>
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

For my column *aprobado* I get the value and use an *ngIf clause to create a span with the string I want to show.

I guest that your getting troubles with the *null* values, to ask if the value is *null*, use `!value`, don't `null !== value`

Is working!
[image]

Comment: hi man, i also tried that way but I have the same result: in the table I always see 'true' or 'false' ...
If I remove the item prop from ngx-datatable-column nothing comes out ... can it be a clue?